# Fotorama - Works in IE, Firefox but not in Chrome (uploaded to server)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fotorama

Ok, i tried to search and never found something for a solution to my issue.

I have **fotorama.js** and fotorama.css working in my site when offline: Chrome, IE, Firefox. and when i put files online (on the server) it works for IE, Firefox and even Chrome for my smartphone.

But in my notebook, chrome explorer, doesn't show at all the fotorama photo slides. i can see the img of picture loading before it "loads" but it appears empty.

Look at screenshots. (I don't know if i should post another screenie, let me know)

[Different view according to explorer: Online/Offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iiMi.png)

[Code in dreamweaver / Source in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUVd5.png)

Can someone help me understand why it's not showing in Chrome live but it does offline? Why the same code works for other navigators such as Internet Explorer and Firefox but not in Chrome?

Comment: FIX: name of the files were ads1.png identified by AdBlocks as an ad, Changing name of the files did the work. It's better than disabling AdBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Adblock blocks the images. Try disabling it for your page

Comment: Reason: name of the files were ads1.png identified by AdBlocks as an ad, Changing name of the files did the work.